Business card dimensions, what am I doing wrong?
I'm trying to make a business card from this template:

Here's an MWE:
\documentclass[11pt,showtrims]{memoir}

\setstocksize{56mm}{96mm} 
\setpagecc{50mm}{90mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{45mm}{75mm}{*}
\settrimmedsize{50mm}{90mm}{*}
\setulmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{5mm}{*}{*}

\setheadfoot{0pt}{0pt}
\setheaderspaces{1pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=.4,  %% adjust
hshift=3mm,
vshift=3mm,
pages=1,
contents={\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{example-image-a}}
}

\begin{document}
\trimLmarks

\null\vfill
 \begin{center}

\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}
\vfill

\end{center} 

\clearpage
\NoBgThispage

\centerline{Some text here}

\end{document}

As you can see, things don't center as expected:

I have a feeling the solution is simple, but what is it?

What exactly are you trying to do on that first page? Why is \vfill inside center? If I need to place something exactly I'd just use absolute positioning. Also consider using the background hook (less packages, less things that can go wring)

Hej Lars! I just need the smaller image centered vertically and horizontally. And yes, the vfill should of course be outside the centering.

If you replace empty by showlocs, you'll see it is a lot better to place the image globally. Give me 5min

It is probably better to absolute position here.
Here we use the shipout backgroup hook.
If you are designing a business card, then I'll do both sides using absolute positioning so you don't have to fight various things.
\documentclass[11pt,showtrims]{memoir}

\setstocksize{56mm}{96mm} 
\setpagecc{50mm}{90mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{45mm}{75mm}{*}
%\settrimmedsize{50mm}{90mm}{*}
\setulmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{5mm}{*}{*}

\setheadfoot{0pt}{0pt}
\setheaderspaces{1pt}{*}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{empty}


\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
scale=1,
angle=0,
opacity=.4,  %% adjust
hshift=3mm,
vshift=3mm,
pages=1,
contents={\includegraphics[width=\stockwidth,height=\stockheight]{example-image-a}}
}


\trimLmarks
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_clear:N \l_tmpa_box
\hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box {\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{
  \put(\dimexpr0.5\stockwidth-0.5\box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box,
  \dimexpr-0.5\stockheight-0.5\box_ht_plus_dp:N \l_tmpa_box){\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-b}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

~ % to trigger a shipout



\clearpage
\NoBgThispage

\centerline{Some text here}

\end{document}



Hmmm.... Some text here seems a bit off center. Or it's me?

@Rmano I haven't touched the text on page 2 at all. As mentioned I'd recommend globally positioning the text on the back side for maximum control. It was just a coincidence that page 2 was in the example image.

@Rmano if you replace {empty} by {showlocs} you can see that the margins are not symetrical compared to the paper choice. But the text is centred inside that block.
